# React Native - onTouchStart vs PanResponder for multiple touches per second

Tags: javascript, react-native, touch, gesture

I'm developing an app with React Native which has to respond to tap gestures as soon as possible because more than one tap event can be fired in a second. No need for double tap or move gestures, but need to take care of simultaneous taps. I've been testing with both `onTouchStart` and `PanResponder | onPanResponderGrant` and seen that:

- `onTouchStart` is fired twice when two taps are simultaneous, while `onPanResponderGrant` is called just once.
- `onPanResponderMove` is fired even when I have `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder` to `false`, and it's fired many times when  two taps are simultaneous, or when there are several taps in a second.
- When several taps are done in a second, `onTouchStart` works fine, but `onPanResponderGrant` is fired less times.

Based on above reasons, I think that I'd better use `onTouchStart`.

Now the question is: **Should I use `onTouchStart` even when [React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html) suggest to use the `PanResponder` for multi-touch gestures?**

> PanResponder reconciles several touches into a single gesture. It makes single-touch gestures resilient to extra touches, and can be used to recognize simple multi-touch gestures.

Or am I missing something of `PanResponder`?

**Edit:**

Also, `gestureState.numberActiveTouches` is always 1, event when two taps are simultaneous. I thought that this could do the trick.

Comment: Is this for a scroll view?

Comment: @sooper - No, it's for some drums.

Comment: Hi @Manolo , is my answer satisfying? please accept it if so, otherwise let us know what's missing :). (edit: ah my bad, the bounty is replacing the check icon I suppose)

Comment: @Jeremie - Well, your answer is based on common sense and makes sense, but what about multi-touch gestures? They won't be fired simultaneously. And why does not work with `PanResponder`? Is it just a not documented behaviour?

Comment: to detect multitouch, I suppose we must tolerate that user is not going to press 3 fingers at the exact same time, so the API leaves some delay for the user to make it happen. this explains why it get triggered a few times per second and not more.
I'm not sure I understand your comment "multi touch gestures won't be fired simultaneously". sounds complicated to me, you expect the user pressing at the same time 2 different drums with multiple fingers?

Comment: @Jeremie - That's it. Two drums at the same time with two fingers.

Comment: ah so that means 4 fingers in total? using multi touch with 2 fingers on each drum?
In that case how can onTouchStart make it work? I guess it is triggered by every single touch? so it should make 4 sounds (2 per drum)

Comment: @Jeremie- Yes. That's why I wanted to use `PanResponder`

Answer (score 11):

From the definition of PanResponder, I understand that it's used to interpret a multi-touch gesture and render 1 action. 
Like I tap with 2 fingers on an image and I could get the image copied to the clipboard.

While it seems you want a different behaviour: I you tap with 2 fingers on 1 drum cymbal, you want to get 2 sounds.
It's as if you were dividing your drum cymbals into an infinity of buttons, and whatever you do, for every tap, you'll get one separate sound.

Then you don't want to use PanResponder, because it's going to try to interpret a bunch of movements into a single sound, while you want every movement to generate a separate sound. And onTouchStart simply gets the job done. So you are probably doing the right thing with it!